# Android IntentService and state

Tags: android, intentservice

I love IntentService and try and use it whenever I have to write a Service.

However I have to perform a long task (~4 seconds) at least once, when the application starts. The task is to load a raw resource (a certificate) and use it for all web service calls. Currently I'm loading it each time a web service call is made, which is obviously not a real solution.

Because IntentService is stateless I can't keep the certificate around between requests. What are my options other than writing a "normal" Service and implementing the lifecycle carefully to check when the certificate should be (re)loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The task is to load a raw resource (a certificate) and use it for all web service calls.

Loading a raw resource should take milliseconds. Use Traceview to figure out why it is taking ~4 seconds.

> Currently I'm loading it each time a web service call is made, which is obviously not a real solution.

Loading a raw resource every time seems like a perfectly viable solution. It's not like you have another choice.

> What are my options other than writing a "normal" Service and implementing the lifecycle carefully to check when the certificate should be (re)loaded.

That would be a really bad idea.

Users greatly dislike developers who keep services running when they shouldn't. Users attack apps like this with task killers and force-stops in Settings. Once that happens, on Android 3.1+, your app will **never run again** until the user starts up one of your activities.

Also, Android will terminate your everlasting service after a while, once again to protect users from poorly-written services.

Focus instead on optimizing the ~4 second operation.

Comment: You were right, reading in the resource seems to be ok. I used traceview to see what was going on, it seems the offending method is in the BouncyCastle library. org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA1Digest.processBlock had an Exclusive time of 4093. It also has 4078 recursive calls.

Comment: Not sure how accurate my previous comment was, I can say the offending code is `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
   ks.load(stream, password);`

Comment: @Jack: I haven't decoded certs with `javax.crypto`, so I have no idea if that is an expected duration or not. Sure seems long. One workaround you can do is cache the resulting `KeyStore` in a static data member. You don't indicate how often the `IntentService` is being invoked. There's a chance that your process will still be around when the alarm(?) or whatever trigger mechanism occurs and the service is started up again. In that case, you can use the cached `KeyStore` rather than re-loading it again. This way, you keep the `IntentService` and some % of your runs can skip the overhead.

Comment: I will have a look at this, but I thought IntentService was destroyed after completion of `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`. Anyway, the service isn't called that frequently, so I guess there's a high chance it won't still be around.

Comment: @Jack: "I thought IntentService was destroyed after completion" -- it is, if the work queue is empty. However, just because the *service* is destroyed does not mean the *process* is terminated.